# avahi works only few minutes

Tags: buildroot, armv7, avahi

I use avahi v0.7 compiled with buildroot 2019.02 to armv7 target.
The compilation works fine.

After service start or system start, I can ping (from other computer) my device with `ping wpb-the.local`. But after few minutes 1 or 2 (on the same computer) I got `ping: wpb-the.local: Name or service not known` from Ubuntu or `Ping request could not find host wpb-the.local. Please check the name and try again.` from windows.

On device side the daemon still running and there is no error in messages.
And if I stop the service and restart it, then it's working during few minutes again.

I don't understand why. Do you have any hint ?

Best regards

JM

Comment: Is your device idle or something is running in the background?

Comment: nop always active, there is a web server on it, and the web site is available with ip v4 or v6. And I still ping with ip

Comment: You said there are no error messages on the device. Are you starting it with the `-D | --daemonize`? Also, you could try to use the `--debug` option to better analyze what's happening.

Comment: Yes the service start with -D

Comment: # /usr/sbin/avahi-daemon --debug
Found user 'avahi' (UID 1000) and group 'avahi' (GID 1000).
Successfully dropped root privileges.
avahi-daemon 0.7 starting up.
WARNING: No NSS support for mDNS detected, consider installing nss-mdns!
Loading service file /etc/avahi/services/sftp-ssh.service.
Loading service file /etc/avahi/services/ssh.service.
Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth1.IPv6 with address xx.
New relevant interface eth1.IPv6 for mDNS.
Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth1.IPv4 with address xx.
New relevant interface eth1.IPv4 for mDNS.

Comment: Network interface enumeration completed.
Registering new address record for xx on eth1.*.
Registering new address record for xx on eth1.IPv4.
Server startup complete. Host name is wpb-the.local. Local service cookie is 2229292744.
Service "wpb-the" (/etc/avahi/services/ssh.service) successfully established.
Service "wpb-the" (/etc/avahi/services/sftp-ssh.service) successfully established.

Comment: If after the ping failure it doesn't print anything, I have no clue about what's wrong! Maybe try asking on specific Linux/avahi forums!